# install previous released virtualenv using zipapp

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to create a fallback option for Users to install virtualenv if users are unable to install virtualenv using pip.

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html mentions zipapp but I dont want to use latest version https://bootstrap.pypa.io/virtualenv.pyz. I am looking for a url something like https://bootstrap.pypa.io/**20.7.2**/virtualenv.pyz

Is there a way to find the previous release that is not depended on python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#via-zipapp) says this:

> If you are looking for past version of virtualenv.pyz they are available here: `https://github.com/pypa/get-virtualenv/blob/<virtualenv version>/public/<python version>/virtualenv.pyz?raw=true`

It is dependent on the Python version. But on the [*`pypa/get-virtualenv`* Github repository](https://github.com/pypa/get-virtualenv) you can find quite easily a link that does not restrict to a specific Python version (be aware that you might get something not supported by your Python interpreter):

```
https://github.com/pypa/get-virtualenv/blob/<virtualenv version>/public/virtualenv.pyz?raw=true
```

For `20.7.2`:

- https://github.com/pypa/get-virtualenv/blob/20.7.2/public/virtualenv.pyz?raw=true